# How do i add hyperlink to the json string i get from a subreddit

Tags: json, typescript, hyperlink

```
const allowed = body.data.children.filter((post: {
  data: {
    over_18: any;
  };
}) => !post.data.over_18);
if (!allowed.length) return message.channel.send('It seems we are out of fresh memes!, Try again later.');
const randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * allowed.length)
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(allowed[randomnumber].data.title)
return embed
```

Information: I'm using Discordjs 13 with typescript and I want to make the title a hyperlink that when you click on the text it takes you to the post.
when I do :

```
.setTitle(`[${allowed[randomnumber].data.title}](https://reddit.com${allowed[randomnumber].data.permalink})`)
```

It shows error this function is not callable
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!, i had to use
.setUrl('')